# Can VS Code extensions get URI requests from other programs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I found information on the official docs that `onUri` can be used as an activation event. So, my extension can be activated from, say, a WPF program written in C# by calling the URI such as `vscode://myextension/arg1=foo&arg2=bar`. But nowhere does it say how I can get the arguments that were passed with the URI request. Or even just get a raw string of it.

My question is, can it be done and if not, is there any other way to make a VS Code extension interact with another program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`vscode.window.registerUriHandler()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.registerUriHandler) for this:

> Registers a [uri handler](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#UriHandler) capable of handling system-wide [uris](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Uri). In case there are multiple windows open, the topmost window will handle the uri. A uri handler is scoped to the extension it is contributed from; it will only be able to handle uris which are directed to the extension itself. A uri must respect the following rules:
>
> - The uri-scheme must be the product name;
> - The uri-authority must be the extension id (eg. `my.extension`);
> - The uri-path, -query and -fragment parts are arbitrary.
>     For example, if the `my.extension` extension registers a uri handler, it will only be allowed to handle uris with the prefix `product-name://my.extension`.
>
> An extension can only register a single uri handler in its entire activation lifetime.
>
> - Note: There is an activation event `onUri` that fires when a uri directed for the current extension is about to be handled.

Usage is quite simple:

```ts
vscode.window.registerUriHandler({
    handleUri(uri:vscode.Uri) {
        // do something with the URI
    }
});
```