# How to launch vscode debug configuration from the browser?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a test case reporting scheme delivered in HTML that is complex in its own right and not easily ported to a VSCode extension. I would like to launch a Debug Configuration for each failing test case from the browser displaying the report. I have already been able to modify the report and have added a copy/paste widget for each test case's associated command. However I would like to do something to the effect of:

- Launch a service as a VSCode extension that can handle requests
- Formulate those requests in a way that can dynamically create launch configurations

It may be that I am stuck writing a Debug Adapter without the bells and whistles of interacting with the report.

That being said, if this is a solved problem or has a framework for solving with VSCode (and I realize remote execution could be a Very Bad Thing for VSCode to allow), I have not been able to find it through an existing extension.

I welcome your ideas.

This is perhaps not as open ended as it sounds...my question ultimately is: can VSCode operate as a service to be requested by web interfaces? Even if it could be done via Localhost this would be a boon. If it can be done over ssh with authentication, that would also be a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of getting VSCode to handle requests would be by invoking a `vscode://` URI. This requires your extension to [implement a URI handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55434913/2631715). After the mandatory parts of the URI, you could have arbitrary data with whatever information you need.

Something that might or might not be an issue for your use case is that invoking such a URI triggers a popup in VSCode / doesn't work silently:

[image]

For dynamically creating launch configurations, you can use the [`vscode.debug.startDebugging()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#debug.startDebugging) API.